# Simplify setting values of object using key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

Is there any way to simplify the following code? May be by using underscore js, I went through the docs, but could not find anything which helps me solve with dynamic key value pair.

Object :

```
this.state = {
        media : {
            video : "",
            photos : [{
                title : "Storefront",
                url : "https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/cHyLd9KtSNibpsGlQsny",
                category : {
                    interior : false,
                    exterior : true,
                    closeup : false
                },
                display : {
                    preview : false,
                    featured : true,
                    none : false
                },
                size : "800 x 600",
                attribution_link : "",
                attribution_text : "",
                description : ""
            },
            {
                ...
            }]
       }
}
```

I'm using react, while handleDisplayClick(e) method is being called, the e will be having the key name, I need to update it to true, and the remaining to false.

```js
handleDisplayClick = (e) => {
        var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        if(e == "preview"){
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.preview = true;
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.featured = false;
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.none = false;
        }
        else if(e == "featured"){
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.preview = false;
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.featured = true;
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.none = false;
        }
        else{
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.preview = false;
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.featured = false;
            stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display.none = true;
        }
        this.setState(stateCopy);
    }
```

Comment: You can use `set` of lodash. Refer https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.3#set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify patterns and avoid repeating code. E.g. there is no need to access `stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex]` over and over again. Simply assign the value to a variable and work with that variable.

Here is a shorter implementation:

```
// assuming `e` is either "preview", "featured" or "none"
const photo = stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex];
['preview', 'featured', 'none'].forEach(
  property => photo.display[property] = property === e
);
```

Or without a loop:

```
// assuming `e` is either "preview", "featured" or "none"
Object.assign(
  stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex],
  {
    preview: e === 'preview',
    featured: e === 'featured',
    none: e === 'none',
  }
);
```

---

Also note that `var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);` is only a *shallow* copy. `stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex]` and `this.state.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex]` refer to the same object so I don't think you will gain anything from that. If you want to create a deep copy you need to use `immutable-helper` as shown on the other answer.

Comment: Wow..!! That's so much helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I make use of `immutability-helper` package instead of `underscore.js`. I don't know about the advantages or disadvantages of usign it but it works out like this

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
......
this.state = {
        media : {
            video : "",
            photos : [{
                title : "Storefront",
                url : "https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/cHyLd9KtSNibpsGlQsny",
                category : {
                    interior : false,
                    exterior : true,
                    closeup : false
                },
                display : {
                    preview : false,
                    featured : true,
                    none : false
                },
                size : "800 x 600",
                attribution_link : "",
                attribution_text : "",
                description : ""
            },
            {
                ...
            }]
       }
}

update(this.state, {
    media: {
       photos: {
          0: {
              display: {
                  preview: {
                     $set: (e === 'preview') ? true : false
                  }
                  featured: {
                     $set: (e === 'featured') ? true : false
                  }
                  none: {
                     $set: (e === 'none') ? true : false
                  }
              }
          }

       }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Shubham.

Answer (score 1):

something like this would work for dynamic properties (set options outside or inside, etc) and cover if you were missing some of the keys on the object and didn't want to add them:

```html
handleDisplayClick = (e) => {
    let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    let options = ['preview', 'featured'];
    e = (options.indexOf(e) > -1) ? e : 'none';
    Object.keys(stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display).foreach(key => {
        stateCopy.media.photos[this.state.media.selectedMediaIndex].display[key] = (key === e);
    });
    this.setState(stateCopy);
}
```